# How do I install packages with F17?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, package-management, yum, chrome

I just installed Fedora 17 on my box and I'm having trouble installing packages. I used to think that across all linux os'es all it took was `sudo apt-get install packagae.`

I don't think this is the case here, as this is not working for me. Do I have to some how install apt-get before I can use it? I thought it came pre-configured with F17.

I'm obviously very new to Linux, and any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `apt-get` is the tool on Debian and derivatives, other distributions have other tools. Take a look at the [Pacman Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta).

Answer (score 1):

Fedora (And RHEL, Scientific and CentOS) all use "Yellowdog Update Manager", AKA "yum". Some examples:

Search: `sudo yum search pkgname`

Install: `sudo yum install pkgname`

Update: `sudo yum update`

`rpm` will do some of the stuff that `dpkg` would do on Debian-ish systems.

Here is some more info: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Tools/Apt

Comment: Ah I see. Do OS'es ever use apt-get and yum?

Comment: Not in supported ways that I know of.

Comment: Seems that Fedora might have an `apt` package. Never worked with it myself, so I cannot attest to how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `apt-get` on RedHat based distros, they don't share the same package database with debian based ones, the correct command for installing a package was:

`yum install XXX`

FYI: fedora doesn't have that much package as Ubuntu provides.